# How do I replace a newline in Atom?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

In Atom, If I activate regex mode on the search-and-replace tool, it can find newlines as `\n`, but when I try to replace them, they're still there.

Is there no way to replace a newline-spanning string in Atom?

Comment: If you turn on Regular Expression mode with the .* button on the right, you can type \n as the replacement string to replace the commas.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Looks like Atom matches newlines as `\r\n` but behaves inconsistently when replacing just the `\n` with nothing.

So newlines seem to match `\s+` and `\r\n`, and only "half" of the line-ending matches `\n`.

- If you replace `\n` with a string, nothing happens to the line-ending, but the string is appended to the next line
- If you replace `\r` with a string, nothing happens at all, but the cursor advances.

Comment: Are sure it is an issue with the Atom regex engine as opposed to the file containing different line endings (and Atom not making the difference visual)?

Comment: Don't really care whether the problem is in "the Atom regex engine".  Search-and-replace is behaving in strange and surprising ways.

Comment: Well you didn't answer the second part of my comment - namely is it an actual bug or something without visual feedback?

Your answer wasn't entirely clear on the actual expressions used - did you try "\r?\n$" ?

Or perhaps replace first all occurrences of \r with \n by using "\r\n?$" ?

Comment: It's not my place to call it a bug.  To me, as a user, it's inconsistent and surprising.  The Atom developers are free to define that weird behavior as "working as specified".   Regardless of Atom's internal model [or what that particular file's line-ending mode is] , there is no actual contents of the file for which the above behavior wouldn't be considered weird by me.

Answer (score 46):

It's alittle bit late to answer but i use following term to search and it works with Atom v1.19.7 x64

```
\r?\n|\r
```

BR

Comment: Why is it too late to answer?

Comment: This was the easiest way for me in atom 1.28.2

Comment: This is a time saver, thanks! - Atom 1.60.0

Answer (score 12):

None of these answers helped me.
What worked for me:

1. I just added a new line at the end of the file.
2. Shift + <- (arrow to left)
3. Ctrl + C
4. Ctrl + V in the "Replace in current buffer" line

Just copied the new line and pasted it in :D

Answer (score 6):

**DELETE INVISIBLE LINE BREAKS IN CODE WITH ATOM**
**(using the "Find in buffer" function)**

(- open your code-file with the Atom-Editor)

- Hit cmd(mac)/ctrl(win) + f on your keyboard for activating the Find in buffer function (a little window appears at the bottom atom-screen edge).
- Mark your Code in which you want to delete the invisible Line breaks.
- Click on the Markup-Mode Button and after that on the Regex-Mode (.*) Button and type into the first field: \n
- After that click replace all.

[And Atom will delete all the invisible line breaks indicated by \n (if you use LF-Mode right bottom corner, for CRLF-Mode (very common on windows machines as default) use \r\n) by replacing them with nothing.]

Hope that helps.

Synaikido

Comment: If there was a Markup button, it seems to be gone in later versions of Atom.

Answer (score 3):

You can use backreferencing:

eg. Replace triple blank lines with a single blank line

Find regex: (\r\n){3}

Replace: $1

You can indicate double blank lines with (\r\n){2}  ... or any number n of blank lines with (\r\n){n}. And you can omit the $1 and leave replace blank to remove the blank lines altogether.

If you wanted to replace 3 blank lines with two, your replace string can be $1$1 or $1$2 (or even $1$3 ... $3$3 ... $3$2 ... ): $1 just refers to the first round bracketed expression \r\n; $2 with the second (which is the same as the first, so $1$1 replaces the same way as $1$2 because $1 == $2). This generalizes to n blank lines.

Comment: I think the OP was trying to replace strings that span lines, not blank lines.

Comment: This is great, but the real trick is to use \r\n, which I found surprising.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The purists will probably not like my solution, but you can also transform the find and replace inputs into a multiline text box by copying content with several line breaks and pasting it into the find/replace inputs. It will work with or without using regex.

For example, you can copy this 3 lines and paste them into both find and replace inputs:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Now that your inputs have the number of lines that you need, you can modify them as you want (and add regex if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Heh, very weird, Ctrl+Shift+F does not work too!

Workaround: open Atom Settings, then Core Packages->line-ending-selector, scroll to bottom to see tips about command to convert line endings: 'convert-to-LF'.

To convert: Cmd+Shift+P type 'line' and choose 'convert-to-LF' - done!

You could change default option 'Default line ending' from 'OS' to 'LF'.

Also after settings changed your new files will use 'LF'.

Answer (score 0):

prerequisite: activate 'Use Regexp'

in my version of atom (linux, 1.51.0) i used the following code to add 'export ' after a new line

```
search '\n'
replace '\nexport '
```

worked like a charm

\r\n didn't match anything