# Why can't Atom find these newlines?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I'm trying to clean up a bunch of `.vcf` files that have line breaks in them and having trouble getting Atom to find the line breaks. Usually either `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` will work if "regex" is selected but in this case it isn't finding blank lines at all. Here's a selection:

```
BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0

X-UNKNOWN-ELEMENT;TYPE=objectclass:top
X-UNKNOWN-ELEMENT;TYPE=objectclass:person
X-UNKNOWN-ELEMENT;TYPE=objectclass:organizationalPerson
X-UNKNOWN-ELEMENT;TYPE=objectclass:inetOrgPerson
X-UNKNOWN-ELEMENT;TYPE=objectclass:mozillaAbPersonAlpha
```

I read over this [How do I replace a newline in Atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400866/how-do-i-replace-a-newline-in-atom) but none of the solutions there helped me find empty lines.

I wound up moving to bash to get rid of empty lines: `sed -i '/^$/d' *.vcf` but there are a bunch of other things I'd like to clean up. Stuff like:

```
X-UNKNOWN-ELEMENT;TYPE=E-mail 2 - Type:internet
X-UNKNOWN-ELEMENT;TYPE=E-mail 2 - Value:person@example.com
```

Which should become:

```
EMAIL;TYPE=WORK:person@example.com
```

That is just one example. There are others, they all revolve around matching multi-line strings, something I've never had a problem with before but in this case it just isn't finding the strings if I use the project search.

Comment: did you try `\r\n` ? - it seems like just doing `\r` or `\n` will ignore them (it might read `\r\n` as one char and hence not do anything with it)

Comment: *What* do you want to search for, and *with what* do you want to replace it?

Comment: Is there a *Multiline* option? If yes, turn it on.

Comment: Updated Q -- I did also try `\r\n`; I actually want to replace multiple line breaks with a single line break.

Comment: So, tried `(\r\n){2,}` -> `$1`?

Comment: Yup. "No results found for ..." basically any search that includes a line break. `\r\n` doesn't find any results, `(\r\n){2,}` is no results. Even copying and pasting a multiline segment doesn't work. Always, "No results found for '...'"

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but what finally worked was leaving Atom altogether and doing `sed -i 's/^M/\n/g' *.vcf ` -- now I have regular line breaks.

Comment: This isn't an answer either :), but switch to emacs? Do you know what is actually in the blank lines in your file (e.g. the binary contents?). emacs Hexl mode is good for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sigh.

The answer is: because Atom project search doesn't support multi-line searches, reg-ex or no:

https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/218