# Using Atom's Regex with 'Find in project' to match multiple words in a file

Tags: regex, atom-editor, regex-group

I'm struggling to find the right regular expression and after following the answers in other threads don't think this is a duplicate as they didn't solve my specific issue.

I have lots of files and assuming one of them contains text that looks like this:

```
createdby:me

one of these words should match
```

Would like to be able to retrieve it by matching to, for example, `createdby:me` and `one`.

The closest I've been able to get from a previous example was to use a regular expression like this.

`(createdby:me|one)`

This does return the file, but it also returns any other files which contain either of the terms—I'd like to return only files with both.

Is there a way to match similarly for and instead of or?

The order isn't important as the `createdby:me` will always proceed the search term.

Nor do I need to capture the matches.

Comment: the regex you wrote capture a text which have "createdby:me" or "one" and prefers "createdby:me" - when I believe you need to add {1} in the end of the regex so it would know you expect only 1 appearance. But I'm not even sure I got what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hmm sorry if it wasn't clear. I don't mind if there is more than one occurrence but I'd like to match when both words are present, not either/or.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**(?:createdby:me[\w\W]*one)|(?:one[\w\W]*createdby:me)**

Comment: Thanks but that returns no results for me.

Comment: I just rechecked it and it seem to be the correct one. it will match you the 2 texts in any order in a file. How did you check it?

Comment: I used it as the Regex search term in the Atom finder. Uploaded a screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/OXvznUh

Comment: Ok, after a quick google I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913351/why-cant-atom-find-these-newlines

In short, they just don't support multi-line search